# Firebase Crash Reporting Multiple Issues

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am setting up Firebase Crash Reporting on my iOS App. I have imported the necessary json files and set up the shell script. However, when I click run on the simulator, I get 11 errors all say about the same thing. Here are two of them:

```
warning: dump_syms: /var/folders/5l/20by_c_57fb7jhv3jh72jw9m0000gn/T/com.google.FirebaseCrashReporter.TAlixfZc/**App Name**.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/**App Name**: in compilation unit '/Users/mikelehen/firebase/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Utilities/FUtilities.m' (offset 0x28a2e): `

warning: dump_syms: /var/folders/5l/20by_c_57fb7jhv3jh72jw9m0000gn/T/com.google.FirebaseCrashReporter.TAlixfZc/**App name**.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/**App Name**: the DIE at offset 0x28fc1 has a DW_AT_abstract_origin attribute referring to the die at offset 0x2940f, which either was not marked as an inline, or comes later in the file `
```

When I try to run it on my iPhone I get only four issues.

Also, my name is not mikelehen which is for some reason in one of the issues.

After following the instructions on Firebase's website about simulating a crash, I never get the log output about the crash being uploaded.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:
Here is the script that is in my build phases:

```
JSON_FILE="../**App Name**/ServiceAccount.json"

GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:**App ID**

defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

1. Build Phases --> Run Script
2. Click `Run script only when installing`

Comment: Setting that flag means that the symbol files won't be uploaded when you archive your app for release (rendering them almost useless).

Comment: @Simon  you have a solution ?

Comment: This is now fixed in version 3.11.1 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#3.11.1

Comment: Still seems broken

Comment: it still the same

Answer (score 3):

Those warnings are not harmful for the most part. The `dump_syms` utility that ships with the Cocoapod is not fully productized, so it reports errors using file names of the person who compiled it last (*mikelehen* in this case). We are actively looking into alternatives to `dump_syms` as the warnings are distracting.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Robert, the warnings are innocuous.  Here are some suggestions that might help you out if you're having issues getting a crash to upload:

1) Make sure the debugger is *not* attached when you cause the crash to occur.  It will intercept the exception, and nothing will get reported.  So compile your program, hit stop in the debugger, manually launch the app (in either the simulator or the device), trigger the crash, then relaunch the app (without the crash so the error has time to report).

2) You should see a log message that Firebase Crash Reporting was initialized. If this is missing, make sure you've included the Firebase/Crash pod and called [FIRApp configure];.

3) Within 15 seconds, you should see another message indicating the report has been successfully sent.  Be sure to wait at least 15 seconds.  Reports are uploaded after a delay to avoid interfering with your app startup.

4) After the report has been uploaded, there is a delay of up to 20 minutes before data shows up in the web console.

5) If you're not using cocoapods, make sure you've added the ObjC linker flag in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings.

Answer (score 0):

The dump_syms warnings generated are not harmful and are generated when symbol files are uploaded. So if you want to avoid warnings every time you build, you can create two targets; debug and release.
Then just disable the option of 'Run script only when installing' for Debug and enable it for release.
This will upload the symbol files.